# JAXB with class property with same root

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm rather new to JAXB and have come across a problem which I can't seem to fix.

If I have a simple XML file as follows.

```
<Root>
    <Test>TestStuff</Test>
</Root>
```

I would like to create a class to handle "root" and another to handle "test". I know normally you wouldn't do this but for this example here's the classes I created;

```
@XmlRootElement
class MyElement {
    private String test;
    @XmlElement(name="Test")
    public String getTest() { return test; }
    public void setTest(String test) { this.test = test; }  
}

@XmlRootElement(name="Root")
class Root {
    private MyElement myElement;
    public MyElement getMyElement() { return myElement; }
    public void setMyElement(MyElement myElement) { this.myElement = myElement; }
}
```

When I run the code below I always get null for myElement.

```
@Test
public void testJAXB() throws Exception {
    InputStream xmlInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(".\\files\\test1.xml"));           
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class, MyElement.class);
    Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
    Root root = (Root) um.unmarshal(xmlInputStream);

    Assert.assertTrue(root.getMyElement().getTest().equals("TestStuff"));          
}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction regarding this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following leveraging `@XmlElement` and `@XmlValue`:

**Root**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Root")
class Root {
    private MyElement myElement;

    @XmlElement(name="Test")
    public MyElement getMyElement() { return myElement; }
    public void setMyElement(MyElement myElement) { this.myElement = myElement; }
}
```

**MyElement**

```
class MyElement {
    private String test;

    @XmlValue
    public String getTest() { return test; }
    public void setTest(String test) { this.test = test; }  
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html

---

**UPDATE**

If you are using [**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) (I'm the tech lead) as your JAXB provider you can use the `@XmlPath(".")` extension to map this use case.

**Root**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement(name="Root")
class Root {
    private MyElement myElement;

    @XmlPath(".")
    public MyElement getMyElement() { return myElement; }
    public void setMyElement(MyElement myElement) { this.myElement = myElement; }
}
```

**MyElement**

```
class MyElement {
    private String test;

    @XmlElement(name="Test")
    public String getTest() { return test; }
    public void setTest(String test) { this.test = test; }  
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Unfortunately, the MyElement class will eventually need to contain several elements. For example I may need to add <Other> element to the MyElement class:
    <Root>
        <Test>TestStuff</Test>
        <Other>random text</Other>
    </Root>

Comment: Sorry - the class should have been called MyElements rather than the singular.

Comment: @user1197930 - I have updated my answer with how this could be done with the `@XmlPath` extension in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy).

Comment: Thanks very much Blaise. I'm not currently using MOXy but i did notice the XmlPath annotation when searching the web for a solution to my problem. I does seem to give me the flexibility I need. I'll use this. Thanks again.